# Passing string from form to usercontrol, error object reference required non-static

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass a string from a form to an usercontrol. I searched on this site and i found this code:

```
// form code
public string ID
{
    get { return username_txt.Text; }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnrollFromMicrophone.ID = ID;
}

//user control code
 public string ID
{
    set { textBox2.Text = value; }
}
```

Now the problem is, I get the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Neurotec.Samples.EnrollFromMicrophone.ID.set'

Comment: Where is `EnrollFromMicrophone` defined? Seems like you are using the class name rather than an instance?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (microsoft, visual, c#) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 1):

As the error message already suggest: You need to have an object instance to access a non-static field.

Instead of:

```
EnrollFromMicrophone.ID = ID;
```

you need:

```
var enrollFromMicrophone = new EnrollFromMicrophone(); // or get the instance from somewhere
enrollFromMicrophone.ID = ID;
```

or make the property static:

```
public static string ID { get; set; }
```

And then use it in e.g. the constructor to set the `textBox2.Text`.